# Enable a single warning in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

Is there a compiler switch to enable a single warning in Visual Studio?

The reason I ask is I want to enable warning C4265 which is off by default. My searching has only turned up ways to turn warnings off.

Even Microsoft pages called [How to: Enable or Disable Compiler Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzzzth4.aspx) still only mention disabling.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to turn it on (or off) in the project setting, you have to go to:

`Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line` and then under *Additional Options* you can enter:

`/w3####` to set your warning to level 3, and thus enable it; or you can enter `/wd####` to disable a warning.

---

Current (2015,2017,2019,...) Visual Studio Versions also have a dedicated setting to disable warnings under:

`Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced : Disable Specific Warnings` ... is equivalent to `/wd####`.

Also useful in recent versions: `C/C++ -> All Options` and then filter for e.g. "warn".

It would appear that enabling á la `/w3####` is not yet exposed explicitly.

Comment: The best answer! Thanks a lot! I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere on MSDN.

Comment: Actually does not work with VStudio 2015. Added it to every single project of Synergy, but got still the build error "Please enable it". Use additional parameter **/w34005** for All Configurations.

Comment: @Slesa - of course it works in VS2015. (I just tried it) What did you do? Post a new question.

Comment: My warning I want to enable is 4706. For me it is also not working with VS2017 either with /w34706 nor /w44706.

Comment: @jaba I'm pretty sure that if you write up a proper question and try to include all necessary details, you'll find the problem.

Comment: If you are using /w2, then to enable a specific warning it is necessary to use /w24706. This tells the compiler to treat warning 4706 as a level 2 warning.

Answer (score 27):

```
#pragma warning(default:4265)
```

It might seem like that would set the warning to it's default setting(which would be disabled), but that's not the case.  It turns it on.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28VS.80%29.aspx

You can also do this:

```
#pragma warning(X:4265)
// where X is the warning level(1,2,3 or 4) that you want this warning to be generated at
```

Comment: +1. Yes, the word *default* means *default warning level*, not *default state*. Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't find it myself.

Comment: i was looking for a compiler flag to do this rather than a code change, as then the warning isn't defined project wide, however it seems this is the only way to achieve the result :(

Comment: This will not work if the _default warning level_ of the selected warning is less (in terms of severity) than the level set up in the project properties.

**Example:**
Warning level is set to 3 (/W3), but warning [C4245](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9s7thk1.aspx) has a default level of 4. Using `#pragma warning(default:4245)` will not enable it, but `#pragma warning(3:4245)` does. (this just bit me)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#pragma warning(default:4265)
```

and compile with at least `/W3`.

Here's an explicit example from Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzxffy8c(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

To make the comment of Matthäus Brandl regarding `#pragma warning` more visible:

If you're compiling with a warning level lower than 3, you have to use this syntax:

```
#pragma warning (<warning level>: 4265)
```

Only if you compile with level 3 or higher you can do

```
#pragma warning (default: 4265)
```

because for warning 4265, `default` means level 3 (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzxffy8c(v=vs.100).aspx)).

The [documentation for `#pragma warning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) reads:

> `warning-specifier`   Meaning
>
> `1, 2, 3, 4` Apply the given level to the specified warning(s). This also turns on a specified warning that is off by default.
>
> `default` Reset warning behavior to its default value. This also turns on a specified warning that is off by default. The warning will be generated at its default, documented, level.