# unsigned int (c++) vs uint (c#)

Tags: c#, c++, int, unsigned, uint

Following is the c# code:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        uint y = 12;
        int x = -2;
        if (x > y)
            Console.WriteLine("x is greater");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("y is greater");
    }
```

and this is c++ code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
unsigned int y = 12;
int x = -2;
if(x>y)
    printf("x is greater");
else
    printf("y is greater");

return 0;
}
```

Both are giving different result. Am I missing something basic? Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signed/unsigned comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons)

Comment: General tip: Always make sure both values are from the same type for a comparison

Comment: @Mehrdad: That question is about why signed/unsigned comparisons in C++ cause a compiler warning when the operator is <, >, >=, or <=, but not when the operator is ==.  That's an entirely different question and its answer has very little bearing on the answer to this one.

Answer (score 48):

C++ and C# are different languages.  They have different rules for handling type promotion in the event of comparisons.

In C++ and C, they're usually compared as if they were both unsigned.  This is called "unsigned preserving".  C++ and C compilers traditionally use "unsigned preserving" and the use of this is specified in the C++ standard and in K&R.

In C#, they're both converted to signed longs and then compared.  This is called "value preserving".  C# specifies value preserving.

ANSI C also specifies value preserving, but only when dealing with shorts and chars.  Shorts and chars (signed and unsigned) are upconverted to ints in a value-preserving manner and then compared.  So if an unsigned short were compared to a signed short, the result would come out like the C# example.  Any time a conversion to a larger size is done, it's done in a value-preserving manner, but if the two variables are the same size (and not shorts or chars) and either one is unsigned, then they get compared as unsigned quantities in ANSI C.  There's a good discussion of the up and down sides of both approaches [in the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/preservingrules.html).

Comment: The C++ standard did provide a rule to handle this situation, and when `int` and `unsigned int` is involved, both operand would be converted to `unsigned int`.

Comment: "...they're usually compared as if they were both unsigned..." Every C or C++ compiler is required to convert the `int` to `unsigned int` in this case. This _is_ mandated by a formal standard, because an unsigned can hold a larger value than an int

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I doubled checked to see if you are correct, and as best I can tell, you are.  So I've changed the answer.  I also found more information about the ANSI C standard's conversions and how they work (value-preserving only when size increase conversions are done).  So it's been updated to reflect that as well.

Comment: I removed the negative vote. The answer is much more precise know

Comment: The C behavior makes sense if one regards unsigned integer types as representing members of an abstract algebraic ring, rather than numeric quantities.  Adding a number to an abstract ring yields another ring, somewhat like adding a number to a pointer yields a pointer (though--unlike pointers--ring elements can also be added to each other).

Answer (score 12):

In C++, when you compare an `unsigned int` and a `signed int`, the `signed int` is converted to `unsigned int`. Converting a negative `signed int` to an `unsigned int` is done by adding `UINT_MAX + 1`, which is larger than `12` and hence the result.

In C#, if you are getting the opposite result then it means that in C# both the expressions are being converted to <strike>`signed int`</strike> `signed long` (`long` or `System.Int64`)<sup>1</sup> and then compared.

In C++, your compiler must have given you the warning:

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

**Rule:**
Always take warnings emitted by the compiler seriously!

<sup><sup>1</sup> As rightly pointed out by svick in comments.</sup>

Comment: In C#, the expressions are converted to signed long (`long` or `System.Int64`).

Comment: IIRC, there is no requirement for warning messages in the C++ standard, only error messages. "must" => "should"?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the standard of C#, but in the C++ standard, `usual arithmetic conversions` would be applied to both operands of relational operators:

> ```
> [......enum, floating point type involed......] 
>
> — Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.
>   Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted operands:
>
>     — If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.
>
>     — Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>       unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer
>       conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand with
>       greater rank.
>
>     — Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>       greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, the
>       operand with signed integer type shall be converted to  the type of the
>       operand with unsigned integer type.
>
>     — Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>       represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>       integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall be converted
>       to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
>     — Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type 
>       corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
> ```

Thus, when `unsigned int` is compared with `int`, `int` would be converted to `unsigned int`, and `-2` would become a very large number when converted to `unsigned int`.