# Integer arithmetic produces a strange result (rounding after division?)

Tags: c

Using gcc version 4.8.4 on Linux, short is 16 bit and int is 32 bit.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main( void ){
  unsigned short u = 0xaabb;
  unsigned int   v = 0xaabb;
  printf ("%08x %08x\n", u, (unsigned short)((u*0x10001)/0x100));
  printf ("%08x %08x\n", v, (unsigned short)((v*0x10001)/0x100));
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0000aabb 0000bbab
0000aabb 0000bbaa
```

This can be varied, e.g., by dividing with 0x10, which produces a similar result (+1) for the first case. The effect does not occur if the byte truncated by `/0x100` is less than 0x80. Machine code for the first case (`short u`) looks as if some rounding (addition of 0xFF) is intended.

1. What is the reason for the result or is it a bug?
2. What is the result for other compilers?

Comment: Why do you think there's anything wrong ? What do you expect ?

Comment: I think he/she expect the results to be the same. My only thought is that the temp variable used is a double and when assigning to unsigned short it does a ceiling rounding instead of a floor?

Comment: @MohitJain, well try with gcc on linux. I got the result OP is getting.

Comment: @Olaf: right, wrote too quickly, deleted comment.

Comment: @o_weisman where's double here?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: I did not write about `double. Wrong tab-extension?

Comment: @Olaf sorry I tagged the wrong person

Comment: @o_weisman: Sorry, but that is nonsense. C will never coerce an integer to a floating point unless there is another floating point operand or argument involved. (I really wonder who upvoted that comment)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A literal like `0x10001` will be of type `int` (if it can fit inside an int, which is true in this case). `int` is a signed type.

Since the variable `u` is a small integer type, it gets integer promoted to `int` whenever used in an expression.

`0xaabb * 0x10001` would supposedly give the result `0xAABBAABB`. However, that result is too large to fit inside an `int` on a 32 bit two's complement system, where the largest number for an `int` is `0x7FFFFFFF`. So you get an overflow on a signed integer and therefore invoke undefined behavior - anything can happen.

Never use signed integers when doing any form of binary arithmetic!

Furthermore, the final cast to `(unsigned short)` is futile, because printf argument promotes the passed value to `int` anyhow. Which is strictly speaking incorrect too, because `%x` means that `printf` expects an `unsigned int`.

To avoid all trouble with the unpredictable and limited default integer types in C, use `stdint.h` instead. Also, using unsigned int literals solves a lot of implicit type promotion bugs.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void ){
  uint16_t u = 0xaabb;
  uint16_t v = 0xaabb;
  printf ("%08" PRIx16 " %08" PRIx16 "\n", u, (uint16_t)(u*0x10001u/0x100u));
  printf ("%08" PRIx16 " %08" PRIx16 "\n", v, (uint16_t)(v*0x10001u/0x100u));
  return 0;
}
```

(This code will have argument promotion too, but by using the `PRIx16` format specifier, you tell `printf` that it is now the compiler's business to make the code work, regardless of what type promotions that might be present in the function call.)

Comment: Why would 0xAABBAABB not fit inside an int? It is a 32-bit quantity.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Because the largest possible number is 0x7FFFFFFF. I've made an edit to clarify.

Comment: Right. But I would say, use unsigned for bitwise ops like and, or and bitshifts, but use signed for arithmetic.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: This is wrong advice for arithmetics (Isupport it for bitops, though). Whether you use signed or unsigned depends on what you want to achieve. Here it is perfectly valid. Problems often arise because of mixing them - like here.

Comment: The final cast isn't futile - it just seems so here. It is the result that should be computed. - Do you mean "bit manipulation" where signed ints are to be avoided?

Comment: @ErikAlapää There almost certainly exists no case where you would want to use signed integers together with hex notation literals. All it will cause is subtle bugs and head ache. This is actually a huge problem for the embedded industry, when naive PC programmers try to write hardware programming C code, with their ints and floats.

Comment: You shouldn't use signed numbers when: doing bitwise operations or dealing with hex literals. I suppose a better word might be hexadecimal arithmetic?

Comment: To explain the genesis of the snippet would be "too broad". It wasn't coded in C or C++ in the first place, it was merely used to display the behaviour of gcc's backend.

Comment: @Lundin, yes, saying hexadecimal arithmetic is better. And when I program close to hw, I definitely prefer using specific integer types like e.g. uint16_t etc. It is essential to know how wide your vars are.

Comment: @Olaf: I think the natural thing for integer arithmetic is to used signed int. As discussed in the comments, arithmetic with hex constants may be better using unsigned. In general, I prefer signed int as my default integer variables, since you can e.g. use -1 in return values etc.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: But you are aware `size_t` as returned by the `sizof` operator **is** unsigned, are you? One thing a good C programmer knows is when to use signed and when unsigned. And he is fit with both kinds. Once you move to advanced programming aside the padded armchair of a PC, you might see.

Comment: @Olaf, I have done a lot of 'advanced programming' on embedded systems. What's with your attitude? Of course size_t is unsigned, and of course unsigned quantities are useful. Here is a good discussion, look at the accepted answer and realize that Stroustrup himself recommends signed int as default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795453/why-prefer-signed-over-unsigned-in-c

Comment: @ErikAlapää: Argumentum ad verecundiam is alwas a bad idea. As it shows you have no true argument. As it is useless to discuss a religion, I'll leave it at that. Btw, Stroustrup also mentioned C is a subset of C++. That was is not true for at least >16 years now.

Comment: So you think it is a bad idea to listen to what the language's creator says? I disagree. And for most practical purposes, C++ IS a true superset of C (C99 has some non-C++ constructs, that is well-known). As for argument, I use ints because I want 2 - 3 to return something useful.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: Full-sized unsigned types (which are not smaller than int) behave like members of a wrapping algebraic numbers, rather than numbers.  Small signed types (smaller than int) are often required by specification to do likewise, though not quite as consistently.  Full-sized signed types and small unsigned types behave like numbers in all defined cases, but their behavior is not always defined.

Comment: @supercat Yes, for some uses, it is nice to have unsigned types as commutative, finite rings, e.g. since they wrap around nicely.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: I wish the Standard would add language to so that small unsigned types used with certain operators will promote to full-sized unsigned types in certain constructs where doing so would yield the same result as signed types in all cases where the latter behavior is specified.  As it is, many implementations' small signed types behave more like rings than their small unsigned types.

Comment: @supercat Yes, I guess the promotion (if type fits in signed int, promote to signed, else unsigned) rules wreak havoc with small unsigned type's ring structure.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: On systems with two's-complement integers, the ring structure would hold if compilers simply ignored overflows.  Problems only arise when compilers use the fact that certain combinations of operand values would cause overflow to infer that such combinations of values will never occur; I question whether the value of such inferences in cases where arithmetic results would otherwise behave as a ring comes anywhere close to the havoc such inferences can cause with code that expects a ring.

Answer (score 3):

*Usual arithmetic conversions* at play.

`u` is converted to `int` before multiplication. Since `int` is signed it behaves differently on division.

```
printf("%08x\n", (u*0x10001)/0x100);
printf("%08x\n", (v*0x10001)/0x100);
```

Returns

```
ffaabbab
00aabbaa
```

Strictly speaking multiplication overflow on signed integer is already undefined behaviour, so result is invalid even before the division.

Comment: The problem isn't actually the usual arithmetic conversions though. The problem is that the integer literal is of signed type. Simply adding a `u` suffix to the literal will solve the bug, because then "the usual" will come in and play, and balance all types to be of `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Lundin: If the unsigned short weren't promoted to a signed type, the signedness of the literal wouldn't matter.

Comment: @supercat But it is, so you will either have to explicitly cast the unsigned short into a larger unsigned type, or change the type of the literal. The most pedantic, MISRA-ish code would be something like `((uint32_t)u * 0x10001u) / 0x100u` where you have killed every single implicit promotion. The code has now prevented conversion both from integer promotion rule and from the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: @Lundin: You say "the problem isn't the usual arithmetic conversions"; my point is that it is the way in which such conversions are performed that creates the particular problem at issue.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `u*0x10001` is `int`= causing an overflow of `signed` type and thus undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming 16 bit `short` and 32 bit `int` (typical for x86, ARM and most other 32 bit systems):

You have two types of *undefined behaviour* (UB) in your code. First, you use the wrong type-specifiers in the format strings. `%x` expects an `unsigned int`, while you pass an `unsigned short` extended to `signed int`.

Second - and the one you see here is the first calculation: `u` is converted  to `int` (integer promotions) - not `unsigned int` for the multiplication, because the constant `0x10001` is also `int`. The multiplication invokes UB as it generates signed integer overflow. Once you invoke UB, you are lost and any further interpretation is useless.

Said that, we are now speculating: what happens is that after the multiplication, you likely have a negative value and as the division rounds towards zero (this is a standard requirement), you get the higher negative value. But as you print as unsigned, you see a larger raw (unsigned) value. This because of the 2's complement internal representation of negative values.

---

Note that this outcome is beyond the C standard. In fact the compiler could generate code to format your hard drive or your computer could jump out of the window or [nasal daemons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) could appear. So, correct the errors:

- use `%hx` to print an `unsigned short int`
- e.g. use `u * 0x10001U` to enforce conversion to `unsigned int` for the multiplication. In general it is recommended to always use the `U` (unsigned) suffix if you work with unsigned values.

Comment: I think it is useful to understand what typically happens, so I prefer user694733:s answer. UB is so boring ;)

Comment: @ErikAlapää: Feel free (but no need to comment). Anyway, while you commented, I just added some more details.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your answer, I just think it is interesting to look at what happens when you get a 32-bit signed quantity, divide that and shoehorn it into a 16-bit unsigned quantity.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: I repeat: I already added that while you were typing that comment.

Answer (score 1):

I extended your code a little bit to explain:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main( void ){
  unsigned short u = 0xaabb;
  unsigned int   v = 0xaabb;

  printf ("not casted:\n");
  printf ("%08x %08x\n", u, ((u*0x10001)/0x100));
  printf ("%08x %08x\n", v, ((v*0x10001)/0x100));

  printf ("unsigned short casted:\n");
  printf ("%08x %08x\n", u, (unsigned short)((u*0x10001)/0x100));
  printf ("%08x %08x\n", v, (unsigned short)((v*0x10001)/0x100));

  printf ("u*0x10001:\n");
  printf ("x=%08x d=%d\n", u*0x10001, u*0x10001);

  // Solution
  printf ("Solution:\n");
  printf (">>> %08x %08x\n", u, (unsigned short)((u*0x10001UL)/0x100UL));
  printf (">>> %08x %08x\n", v, (unsigned short)((v*0x10001UL)/0x100UL));
  return 0;
}
```

This leads to the following output:

```
not casted:
0000aabb ffaabbab
0000aabb 00aabbaa
unsigned short casted:
0000aabb 0000bbab
0000aabb 0000bbaa
u*0x10001:
x=aabbaabb d=-1430541637
Solution:
>>> 0000aabb 0000bbaa
>>> 0000aabb 0000bbaa
```

So what you are seeing that the operation `u*0x10001` will generate an `signed int` (32 Bit) value and due to this your result is `d=-1430541637`. If you divide this value with `0x100` you will get the result you got `0xFFAABBAB`. If you are casting this value with `unsigned short` as you did, you get your result = `0x0000BBAB`. If you want to prevent this, that the compiler uses unsigned values for this operation you have to write `UL` as an extension to the numbers.

So you see the compiler is working as expected. You can compile it by yourself here [Code[^]](http://ideone.com/OQqeBo).

Comment: Can you explain why? To me it seems quiet logical and further I tested it with the IDEOne online compiler as you can see in my link.

Comment: Fine you corrected the fault and an explanation is nice, but you missed the actual (and vital) point