# Why is the output wrong?

Tags: c, types

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
      unsigned  x=1;
      signed char y=-1;
      clrscr();
      if(x>y)
       printf("x>y");
      else
     printf("x<=y");
}
```

A signed character has an increased value from -128 to 127. So the expected out put should have been 'x>y', but it isn't. The compiler gives the output - "x<=y". Can you explain why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the comparison the `signed char` gets converted to an `unsigned int` and thus looks like a really big value. I would expect the compiler to warn you - i.e. something in the lines "comparing signed and unsigned stuff is confusing".

This conversion is mandated under "Relational operators":

> If  both  of  the  operands  have  arithmetic  type,  the  usual 
>   arithmetic  conversions  are performed.

Comment: I am sorry, the compiler does not warn. It simply gave the mentioned output. I am using Codeblocks compiler. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**C11 §6.8 al3 p95 :**

> If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are 
>   performed.

**C11 §6.3.1.8 al1 p53 :**

> [...] if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater
>   or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the
>   operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.

So `y` will be promote to an unsigned type, and will be greater than `x` (`1`).

Answer (score 0):

in comparison, if one operand is unsigned, then the other operand is implicitly converted into unsigned if its type is signed!

more to found here : [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons)

Answer (score 0):

In your case signed char is converted to unsigned int, thus we are getting a big positive integer instead of -1. Here is an extract from ANSI C standard draft that explains what happens during usual arithmetic conversions that took place.

> 3.2.1.5 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
>   conversions and yield result types in a similar way.  The purpose is
>   to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.  This
>   pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions: First, if either
>   operand has type long double, the other operand is converted to long
>   double .  Otherwise, if either operand has type double, the other
>   operand is converted to double.  Otherwise, if either operand has type
>   float, the other operand is converted to float.  Otherwise, the
>   integral promotions are performed on both operands.  Then the
>   following rules are applied: If either operand has type unsigned long
>   int, the other operand is converted to unsigned long int. Otherwise,
>   if one operand has type long int and the other has type unsigned int,
>   if a long int can represent all values of an unsigned int, the operand
>   of type unsigned int is converted to long int ; if a long int cannot
>   represent all the values of an unsigned int, both operands are
>   converted to unsigned long int.  Otherwise, if either operand has type
>   long int, the other operand is converted to long int.
>   **Otherwise, if either operand has type unsigned int, the other operand is converted to unsigned int.**  Otherwise, both operands have
>   type int.

Answer (score 0):

Get used to compile with all warnings, i.e. in the case of gcc:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic source.c -o prog
```

In your case the flag `-Wextra` give the following message:

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

That doesn't explain why, but it warns you at least ;) .

The explanation is that a signed variable evaluating to `-1` is equal to an unsigned evaluating to `UINT_MAX` when compared with a relational operator.

The compiler has to do something well defined in that case and this is what people came up with...

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler see comparing an unsigned int with signed int it promote the signed int to unsigned, this mean adding this (in linux box) to the signed one:

```
#define UINT_MAX    (~0U) (defined in this header file : /include/linux/kernel.h)
```

So now you  are comparing  **UINT_MAX - 1 (UINT_MAX + y)** with **x**, which explain clearly the output.

Edit : to be more clear : on 32 bits machine ---> `UINT_MAX =  2 147 483 648 =  2**31`

Regards.