# Equality operand behavior for unsigned and signed types

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons)

So I have the below code, which sets an unsigned int to a negative number, and then does a comparison of the unsigned int with the same negative number. The output I get is "Not Equal".  I understand that when setting the unsigned int to -1, the value of the unsigned int is set to 255 in this case.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  uint8_t test = 0;
  int8_t set = -1;

  test = set;

  if (test == set) {
    std::cout << "Equal";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Not Equal";
  }
}
```

However, what causes the equality operand to return false?  This seems to be in direct contrast with the answer to the similar question [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons) which states

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions,
>   which are defined as follows:
>
> If either operand is of type long double, the other shall be converted
>   to long double.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted
>   to double.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be converted to
>   float.
>
> Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both
>   operands.54)
>
> Then, if either operand is unsigned long the other shall be converted
>   to unsigned long.
>
> Otherwise, if one operand is a long int and the other unsigned int,
>   then if a long int can represent all the values of an unsigned int,
>   the unsigned int shall be converted to a long int; otherwise both
>   operands shall be converted to unsigned long int.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is long, the other shall be converted to
>   long.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is unsigned, the other shall be converted
>   to unsigned.

Thus according to this answer,  since both operand is unsigned, the other shall be converted to unsigned, and the equality should pass. But it clearly is not passing, and as answered already in this question, they are both being promoted as signed ints.

Comment: -Wall -Werror will tell you exactly why. You have a signed/unsigned mismatch. in type-comparisons.

Comment: @larsmans - it's easy to overlook the assignment `test = set`. <g>

Comment: Be careful of using standard library names like `set` as variables.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I know that the code is wrong, I'm just asking about the underlying rules behind the behavior.

Answer (score 9):

It is, indeed, standard behavior. Types that are smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` when used with `==` and most other operators. So `test` gets promoted to `int`, with the value 255. And `set` gets promoted to `int`, but it's a negative number, so its value, both before and after promotion, is -1. Since 255 is not equal to -1, the comparison gives `false`.

The moral is: be careful if you mix signed and unsigned types in comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be contradictory with cases when doing comparison with unsigned ints and signed ints. My question is why is it different?

Comment: @umps - there are values of an unsigned type that can't be represented as the corresponding signed type and vice versa, so the rules for types larger than or the same size as `int` do a different set of promotions.