# C++ comparison expression bug

Tags: c++

There's something wrong with this code, but I can't find what's causing it.

```
bool Parser::validateName(std::string name) {
    int pos = name.find(INVALID_CHARS);               //pos is -1, 
    bool result = ((name.find(INVALID_CHARS)) < 0);   //result is false
    //That was weird, does that imply that -1 >= 0?, let's see
    result = (pos < 0)                                //result is true
    result = ((name.find(INVALID_CHARS)) == -1)       //result is true
    result = (-1 < 0)                                 //result is true
    ...
}
```

Why is the result false at the second line. Is there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: I doubt that. Can you post runnable code on ideone?

Comment: note that additionally using the plural form in `INVALID_CHARS` makes one wonder if this is a string full of invalid chars, and whether you don't want something like `find_first_of`

Comment: Return of find is of type size_t.

Comment: npos is not -1, it is 0xFFFFFFFF. That expression will always be false...

Comment: FWIW, my compiler gives "warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false"

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, I don't know why compiler didn't warn me... I guess I'll check that makefile.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes which compiler are you using? I'm using GNU g++ 4.6.3 and didn't get a warning for that line, but if I compare my own unsigned vs signed variables, compilers does give that warning.

Comment: g++ 4.7.2, with flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @neagoegab: 0xffffffff just happens to be the representation of -1 casted to a 32bit unsigned integer in your implementation. The standard defines npos to be size_type(-1) and size_type to be an implementation defined unsigned integer. Most implementations make this be size_t which on 64bit architectures is often a 64bit unsigned integer. But what its representation is exactly is not specified, and also of no matter since the right way to do things is to compare to std::string::npos

Comment: @PlasmaHH of course, but I wanted to keep it simple... whithout to many explanation so he could dig a little bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` which is of type `std::string::size_type` which is defined to be an implementation defined unsigned integer. Unsigned integers are never smaller than `0`.

You should always compare against `std::string::npos` to check whether `std::string::find` found something or not.

Comment: OK, I'll do that, and I guess your right, but if npos is of type unsigned, how did `pos` have a value a `-1` after runnning the first line.

Comment: @Erandros `size_t p1= -1;  int p2 = p1; std::cout<<p1<<' '<<p2;` Run this code and see

Comment: Why does `((name.find(INVALID_CHARS)) == -1)` compare to `true`  if it uses unsigned integers?

Comment: @Erandros The right way to do this is something like `auto location = name.find(INVALID_CHARS); location != std::string::npos` -- if you lack the auto feature, use `std::string::size_type`.  Pos has a value of `-1` because you cast an unsigned type to a signed type, which can result in a negative value even if the original value wasn't negative (it is common for `unsigned int(-1)` to be the max value of `unsigned int`).

Comment: @Evgeni because "`unsigned`" doesn't mean "positive".

Comment: @Erandros - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons

Answer (score 2):

`std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` when it does not find the requested item. According to the Standard (§ 21.4/5):

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

But see that `string::size_type` is usually `unsigned int`; this means that `-1` is converted into its unsigned equivalent. Usually, 0xFFFF, which is the maximum value for `unsigned int`.

In your second line:

```
bool result = ((name.find(INVALID_CHARS)) < 0);
```

you are comparing two `unsigned int` values (0xFFFF and 0), so this returns `false`. On the other hand, in your fourth line:

```
result = ((name.find(INVALID_CHARS)) == -1)
```

you have an `unsigned int` and an `int`, so promotion rules apply and the `unsigned int` is converted into an `int`; as we saw before, the signed equivalen of `npos` is always -1, so this returns `true`.