# Char Array - Why for loop is not infinite?

Tags: c

I've written the following code to reverse a string in C. The code seems to works properly and that's why I'm confused. Does anyone know why there is not an error here? I was expecting an array out of bounds or an infinite loop on the for loop, but it seems the loop breaks before it gets to negative values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char* str);

void reverse(char* str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str); 

    for(int i = (int)len-1; i<=len; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char string[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
    reverse(string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = (int)len-1; i >= 0; i--)` is what's logically correct. What you had, would be true while `i` is less than `len`, which is always true.

Comment: signed/unsigned comparison is unwise.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5416498/489590

Comment: @Legend so? that doesnt answer his question, why it is working for him, we all know how it is done properly

Comment: @Ulterior it's a logical flaw. I don't know C/C++ and only come from a Java and ASM background. "we all know how it is done properly", well obviously not considering it was done poorly here and you are supporting such acts.

Comment: @Ulterior also, I didn't post as an answer. If I wanted to answer it, I would've posted an answer.

Comment: @Legend its OK, no offense m8

Comment: @Legend we will have to learn to live with that throughout the rest of our life, then...

Comment: The same mistake as in the classic `size_t len; for(len=x; len>=0; len--){}` bug, but it makes the code work instead of fail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

size_t is generally defined as unsigned. When you compare a signed and an unsigned number or equal rank the signed number is converted to unsigned. Since the signed number is probably represented in two's complement in your machine negative numbers are actually larger.

So once `i` hits -1, it is larger the comparison thinks its larger than len.

You can see this is happening by turning on warning in your compiler.

Compiling your program with clang -Weverything produces this warning

```
unsigned.c:10:30: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 
                  'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
```

Comment: Detail fixes: When you compare a signed and an unsigned number _of equal rank_ the signed number is _converted_ to unsigned.

Comment: Strangely enough, rewriting as for(size_t i = len-1; i<=len; i--) also appears to work fine. For reference, I'm using GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) x86_64-apple-darwin.

Comment: @sager89 since size_t is unsigned 0-1 is large. (MAX_INT) about 4 billion. (2^32-1). The integer rolled over.

Comment: @FDinoff Except in my case, size_t is 2^64-1 or 18446744073709551615.