# CUDA kernel infinite loop when comparing int to threadIdx.x

Tags: cuda

I had an issue with a much larger kernel, but it seems to distil down to the following code, from which the kernel never returns.  Can someone please explain why there is an infinite loop?

```
__global__ void infinite_while_kernel(void)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index >= threadIdx.x) {
        index--;
    }
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    infinite_while_kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, the below kernel also gets stuck:

```
__global__ void not_infinite_while_kernel(void)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index >= (unsigned int) 0u*threadIdx.x) {
        index--;
    }
return;
}
```

Replacing `threadIdx.x` with `0` in the original kernel returns, as expected.  I'm using the v5.5 toolkit, and compiling with the `-arch=sm_20 -O0` flags.  Running on a Tesla M2090.  I do not currently have access to any other hardware, nor toolkit versions (it's not my system).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code hangs in ordinary C++ as well (try it):

```
int main(){

  int index = 0;
  while (index >= 0U){
    index--;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

When comparing a signed to unsigned value, the [compiler converts the signed value to unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons).

`threadIdx.x` is an unsigned value.  An unmarked `0` constant in your code is not.

As an unsigned comparison, your test is always true, so the while loop never exits.

Also note that your `__global__` function should be decorated with `void`.

Finally, without a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or other barrier in your code following the kernel launch, your program will exit "normally" anyway, even if the kernel hangs.

So I don't think the code you've posted actually reproduces the issue you're describing, but if you add the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` it will.

Comment: Ah yeah.  My full code has a blocking call later, so I see the hang. Will add this for completeness, but marking as correct since this fixed it.  Is it possible to get nvcc to warn about this?  I don't see the option...

Comment: I don't know of a way to make `nvcc` warn about this.