# sizeof operator giving output false while using in this way

Tags: c, unix, unsigned-integer

I am not able to understand why this piece of code is giving output False:

```
   if (sizeof(int) > -1)
       printf("True");
   else
       printf("False");
```

As I tried to print what `sizeof(int)` is returning is 4.

Comment: I'd like to understand in which case this comparison makes sense?  Have you ever heard of any type which has negative size? ;-)

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, and **MIND THEM**.

Comment: Don't write such nonsense in the first place, I'd rather say.

Comment: It's a nice reminder why `x > -1` ≠ `x >= 0` even for whole numbers like integers.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons

Answer (score 3):

The result of the `sizeof` operator has type `size_t`. Your `-1` is a `signed int`. When the two are compared, the latter is converted to `size_t`, which results in a rather large unsigned value.

Comment: It in fact results in the maximum unsigned value for the type that is `size_t`

Answer (score 1):

By standard `sizeof` returns an [unsigned integer type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) `size_t`. Although the exact type is implementation defined it is certain to be unsigned. When you try to compare it to the signed integer `-1`, `-1` gets converted to max value of this type(try writing `(unsigned)-1` and examine the value) and thus the comparison is false.