# Don't understand simple C Program if/else result

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long a= 100000;
    long b = -1;
    if (b > a)
        printf("yes\n");
    else
        printf("No\n");

    return 0;
 }
```

Why the output comes "Yes" when we know 100000 > -1 . So accordingly it should print "NO" but being a naive, i can really get it

Comment: First problem `void main()` is a very old way of defining `main()`, that means that you are using very outdated resources.

Comment: Second problem: You haven't enabled warning flags or have ignored them.

Comment: This should clear things : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compare `long` and `unsigned long` then both get converted to `unsigned long` first so (depending on the platform) the `-1` value becomes `0xFFFFFFFF`. The result is clear then.

Comment: how the value -1 becomes in 0xFFFFFFFF ??? sorry @dlask will give a gist or any kind of link ?

Comment: it's called two's complement

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
if (b > a)
```

you are comparing an `unsigned long` with a `long`, which leads to the errors.

Simply change

```
 unsigned long a= 100000;
```

to

```
  long a= 100000;
```

Comment: Okay i get what u meant , but i was wondering how **unsigned** made the value of **long a** less than **long b** ?

Comment: @SJith: See, unsigned means its values will be from 0, and no negatives can be included. So when you try to fit a negative number into an unsigned, implicitly it is converted into a non-negative. So, -1 will be converted to, say 2^32-1, which is larger than 10000, so you get your output.