# Explanation of a macro in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, macros

In kernel 2.4.37, there is a macro in [page.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-i386/page.h?v=2.4.37#L136) like this:

```
struct page *mem_map;
struct page *page;

#define VALID_PAGE(page)  ((page - mem_map) < max_mapnr)
```

I know `mem_map` is an array of `struct page`, `page` is a `struct`, so what does `page - mem_map` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will compute the index of corresponding page in mem_map array means which number of page it is in mem_map array, let say it as pfn or page frame number for linux (linux assumes that mem_map array starts with 0th pfn to the max pfn) , adding a [PHYS_PFN_OFFSET](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/memory.h#L153) to pfn will give you the actual physical page frame in your memory map.
[__page_to_pfn](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/memory_model.h#L31)

max_mapnr is the limit of maximum number of mapped pages or maximum page frame number.
[set_max_mapnr](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/init.c#L481)

I hope it clears your doubts.

Answer (score -1):

Humm, I'm not sure but maybe a pointer adresses comparaison ?

I mean,  if one of them is a array and it's not dereferenced the operations are apply on adresses I suppose.

Edit: (precision)

So, in this case I think this operation is for check if "page" is in range of the adresses array "mem_map".

We can represent like this: [Graphic representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2N1Z.png)

---

### Utility of Macro:

So, "mem_map" is adresses of the begin of array, suppose: 0x0...5.
The size of "mem_map"(max_mapnr) array is: 5.

We want to know if "page" adresses is in the range of "mem_map" array.

### True Case:

Suppose "page" is in "mem_map", 2e element. We can suppose his adresses is something like: 0x0...7;

Now we do operation: `((0x0...7 - 0x0...5) < 5)`.
We obtain 2. So "page" adresse is in mem_map.

### False Case:

Otherwise if  "page" is out of the array (0x0...D): We the result will be 8. So, 8 is not less than "max_mapnr"(5). So this page is not in the "mem_map" array.

---

And if the adresses is bellow the array adresse (0x0...2):
The result of `((0x0...2 - 0x0...2))` will be a negative value. And in that case they comparaison with "max_mapnr"(unsigned long) is not possible.

I found this topic explain why better than me:

[Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons)

So for resume:
You canno't do operations between negative(signed) and unsigned value in C cause he cast them automaticaly. In others terms, when you do `(-3 - U_nbr)`, it's same if you do: `(((unsigned)-3) - U_nbr)`. And in option, normaly if you compile with `gcc -Wall` flags, and you don't cast manually your value you will have an compilation Warning message.

For testing I tried to run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        unsigned long test = 0x0000F;
        unsigned long test2 = 0x0000A;
        unsigned long weird = 0x00002;
        char* pt1 = "This is first test string !";
        char* pt2 = "This is a test string";

        printf("Try to make operation on two unsigned long result must be 5: %lu\n", (test - test2));
        printf("Try to make operation between unsigned long result must be negative, so he will be cast: %lu\n", (weird - test2));
        printf("Let's try the same with real adresses: %lu\n", (pt2 - pt1));
        printf("And this is what happens with negative value: %lu\n", (pt1 - pt2));
        printf("For be sure, this is the lenght of string 1. %lu\n", strlen(pt1));
        return (0);
}
```

The ouput is:

```
Try to make operation on two unsigned long result must be 5: 5
Try to make operation between unsigned long result must be negative, so he will be cast: 18446744073709551608
Let's try the same with real adresses: 28
And this is what happens with negative value: 18446744073709551588
For be sure, this is the lenght of string 1. 27
```

So, as we can see, the negative value is casted in Unsigned long and return a overflowed one. And if you make this comparaison with max_mapnr you will see he is "out of range".

---

*Thank's to AnshuMan Gupta for the "weird case".*

Comment: "But I'm not sure of the behavior of this MACRO with a pointer not in array but less than "mem_map" pointer". i think that is not the case because you will have to always pass a page to to VALID_PAGE after converting it to page either by pfn_to_page or virt_to_page.

Comment: @avallete Yes,what I care about is the Weird Case. What if the pointer does not point to the array.

Comment: @HuangJie if page is pointing to below mem_map then (page - mem_map) yields a negative value and thus comparison of negative value  with max_mapnr (lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L80) which is a unsigned long (negative value < max_mapnr) will always false and page will not be valid page. thus there is no weird case. hope this will clear the weird case doubt

Comment: @AnshuManGupta Thank you for your explanations I edit my post in consequences.