# Weird result with C strings

Tags: c++, string, strlen

I expect "match!" when the `n2` tail is the same that the `n1` tail, otherwise, "do not match!".
Example of "match!": `n1 = 123456` and `n2 = 3456`.

The problem is when I enter, for example, `n1 = "45"` and `n2 = "645"`. It should not match, but the output is "match!".

```
bool different_tail = false;

char n1[11], n2[11];

cin >> n1 >> n2;

for(int i = strlen(n1)-strlen(n2); i < strlen(n1); i++){
  if(i < 0 || n1[i] != n2[i-(strlen(n1)-strlen(n2))]){
    different_tail = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(different_tail)
  cout << "does not match!" << endl;
else
  cout << "match!" << endl;
```

I don't want to use other ways to solve the problem (like, strcmp, etc...), I want to understand what's happening.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Nathan, strlen(n1)-strlen(n2) is -1 and the 'for' is not executed... I don't know why. And I can't debug nothing else to know about that.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that with `n1` being `45` and `n2` being `645`, the loop variable `i` will start at `-1`, i.e. it is negative.

However, [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) yields an unsigned value (a value of type [`size_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/size_t)). When comparing a signed with an unsigned value (as you do in the expression `i < strlen(n1)`), the signed value is converted to an unsigned value. Since it's negative, this causes an underflow, so `i` is a very large value -- larger than `strlen(n1)`.

You can observe the same effect with e.g.

```
int i = -1;
size_t x = 5;
if (i < x) {
  cout << "yes\n";
} else {
  cout << "no\n";
}
```

This program prints `no`.

You can avoid your issue by casting the return value of `strlen`, i.e. change your loop condition to

```
i < static_cast<int>(strlen(n1))
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons) (and the accompanying answers) provide a more in-depth discussion of this topic.

Comment: Oh... I got it. Very weird for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

`for(int i = strlen(n1)-strlen(n2); i < strlen(n1); i++){`

here `i` is an `int` whereas `strlen(n1)` is an `size_t`(an unsigned integer type). Performing "less than" operator between signed and unsigned type will convert all operands to unsigned types, in this case `unsigned(i)` becomes a very large integer, so the for loop is never executed.

BTW, it's not a good practice to use `strlen` in for loop, since `strlen` is an expensive function and will be called at every iteration. You can store `strlen` result in an variable and use the variable instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that!