# QVariant signed/unsigned comparisons

Tags: c++, qt, unsigned, signed

The QVariant type of the Qt Framework offers comparison operators `<, <=, >, >=`, but they work unexpected on signed/unsigned integer arguments mismatch:

```
QVariant(-1) < QVariant(0u) yields false
QVariant(0u) > QVariant(-1) yields false
```

Does anybody know if this is a bug, or is this intended?
Do this operators always return false on singed/unsigned mismatch?

Btw, I'm using Qt 5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QVariant(-1) < QVariant(0u)` will call built-in comparators of `int` and `unsigned int`. Basically, `(int(-1) < uint(0)) == false` (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons) it is explained why).

If you want different behavior, convert values before comparison explicitly with [toInt()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toInt) or similar methods:
 `QVariant(-1).toInt() < QVariant(0u).toInt() == true`