# Implicit conversion using Comparison operator

Tags: c

In the below code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

int main(void){
  int array[] = {7,5,4,3,2};
  int index = -1;
  for(;index <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2;index++)
    printf("%d\n", array[index+1]);
  return 0;
}
```

---

`index <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2` fail before printing single element.

Is it not the condition `-1 <= (5-2)`, that is being evaluated in `for-loop`?

Comment: Signed / unsigned comparison? What will `-1` become in that invalid comparison?

Comment: yeah signed unsigned comparison, I saw a question like this some time ago, cannot find the duplicate but it is one!

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` yields `5` which is of type `size_t`. As a result, the type of the expression `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])-2` is also `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type. The LHS of the comparison also gets promoted to `size_t` type (see [usual arithmeic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8)) and `-1` is equal to SIZE_MAX (the maximum value that a `size_t` can hold) after the conversion.

Hence, the comparsion `index <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2`, which is equivalent to `SIZE_MAX <= 3`, is false.

Answer (score 1):

The division `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` results in an unsigned int so when comparing with index = -1 or subtracting from it will be implicitly cast to unsigned int i.e. 0xffffffff and so the condition fails.

Instead just do a explicit cast in your macro

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (int)(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
```

personally i would instead use an argument to your TOTAL_ELEMENTS

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS(ar) (int)(sizeof(ar))/sizeof(ar[0]))
```

to make to code a little bit more readable.

Comment: I know that C is loosely typed, but not at a level that it implicitly converts signed to unsigned. I could only see this as overhead feature in C

Comment: @overexchange normally a compiler would give you a warning about implicit cast if you haven't turned it off but C doesnt prevent you from doing what you want

Comment: Am using cygwin

Comment: @overexchange Try to add `-Wall -Wextra` flags to your compiler and see if it will produce any warnings.

Comment: I notice that MSVC only gives a warning if I assign the macro value to an `unsigned int` first, and use that variable in the loop.

Comment: I heard of implicit and explicit type conversion in Java, now going further signed/unsigned conversion in C

Comment: @overexchange please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons).

Comment: Converting `size_t` to `int` is a bad idea: `size_t` could be larger. It'll work in a toy example, of course, but not always in the real world. Better stick to unsigned types: declare `index` of type `size_t` — `unsigned int` could overflow.

Comment: @Gilles true, i think the problem is that he wants to use -1 so I adapted it so that he could still use -1

Answer (score 0):

In the comparison `index <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2`, the left-hand side `index` has the type `int`, and the right-hand side `TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2` has the type `size_t`¹. The two operands of the operator have different types, so they need to be converted to a common type. The common type always has the larger of the two sizes², which is `size_t` (which may be the same as `unsigned int` on 32-bit machines, but it usually larger on 64-bit machines). And the common type is unsigned in this case, because the right-hand side is at least as large.

The common type is always chosen so that it can represent the maximum positive value of both types. If this results in an unsigned type then it can't represent negative values.

Here the variable `index` is an array index, so it should have the type `size_t`. The type `int` may be too small to represent all array indices.

`size_t` is an unsigned type; unsigned values are easier to manipulate, and have predictable behavior on overflow, so generally speaking you should use unsigned types unless you need negative values. (Overflow is still a problem with unsigned types, but at least the behavior is well-defined so the problem is easier to debug.) Here there's no point in having a variable with negative values: use `index` as the array index, instead of the array index minus one, and then it'll start at 0 instead of 1.

```
size_t index;
for(index = 0; index <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS-1; index++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[index]);
}
```

¹  <sub>Or `unsigned int` if `size_t` is smaller than `int`, e.g. if it's `unsigned short`, but it would be very unusual for a C implementation to be like this.</sub> 
²  <sub>In technical terms, the larger of the two ranks.</sub>