# Why do I get out_of_range with substr call?

Tags: c++

I was working on a competitive programming question. I wrote this question to count the number of "VK" substrings.

```
int count(string test) {
    int answer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= test.size()-2; i++) {
        if (test.substr(i,2) == "VK")
            answer++;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Why did I receive this error message when I try just "V" as the argument?

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
> what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 2) > this->size() (which is 1)
> ```

Shouldn't the statements in the for loop not execute because the loop's condition failed?

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't the statements in the for loop not execute because the loop's condition failed?

Yes, you are right, but *the condition didn't fail*!. `test.size()` is a `std::size_t`, an implementation defined unsigned type.

The key here is that it is *unsigned*, meaning that it can overflow without invoking undefined behavior. When you pass `"V"`, `test.size()` is `1`. Then, `1 - 2` is equal to `-1`, but this overflows as an unsigned number cannot take negative numbers! The result is a *very* large number.

So, the loop executes a lot more times than you would have thought, and that is were the `std::out_of_range` exception comes from: On the second iteration, you are already accessing index `1`, which is out of range (as `test` has size `1`).

You need to introduce a pre-condition check:

```
if (test.size() < 2)
    return 0;
```

Comment: Isn't it: if (test.size() < 2)

Comment: This is good all the way up to the suggested fix. The `size` test would need to be `< 2` or `<= 1` but personally I suggest just changing the OP's `for` loop condition by adding `2` to both sides of the equation: `for (int i = 0; i + 2 <= test.size(); i++)`

Comment: @Rakete111 So "test.size() - 2" remains an unsigned int even when compared to the integer i?

Comment: @BozSteinkalt Yes, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons) for more information about that.