# Is this loop implicitly casting an int to size_t?

Tags: c++, loops, implicit-conversion

I ran into a bug in my program:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objArray.size() - 1; ++i)
```

In my case objArray.size() is an unsigned long long and an empty vector minus 1 equals about 18 quintillion. I was wondering, does the loop on every iteration have to cast an int to an unsigned long long? I checked the assembly and while using an int creates different code than size_t without optimisations, with -O2 specified it generates exactly the same assembly. Does this mean it's not implicitly casting?

I don't understand assembly, but the code it generated was:

```
test rcx, rcx
je .L32
add rdx, rax
```

and then :

```
cmp rdx, rax
jne .L28
```

Comment: Just to be certain... your CPU is 64 bit, right?

Comment: Note that, supposing `i` is constant in the loop, the compiler may assume that `i` is never negative. So it may just reinterpret as `unsigned` and compare

Comment: My CPU is 64 bit. In Visual Studio running in 64 bit mode it was an infinite loop. Even after the int got over about 2.2 billion it just overflowed and kept going, because it was comparing to about 18 quintillion each time I think. The assembly I added was from godbolt.org

Comment: Just for confirmation though, is it always better form to use a size_t in this situation? Most code I see floating around doing it the way I did it seems kinda normal.

Comment: The answer to the title question, without needing to look at the code, is no. There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a **conversion**.

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by a compiler optimization. The c++ standard says that overflow of signed integral types is undefined. In this case, `i` starts at `0`. Supposing that `i` is not written to in the loop, the compiler can thus deduce, that `i >= 0`, since overflowing is undefined behaviour and can be pruned.

Normally, for an signed-unsigned comparison, the signed value would have to be converted to the unsigned type following the rules you can [see here](/a/5416498/3102935). These rules are the reason for the compiler warnings when comparing a signed and unsigned type (leading to confusion, e.g. `-1 > 2U`
 is true). In this case, that doesn't matter though.

With the assumption `i >= 0` and 2-complement signed types though, the compiler can safely reinterpret `i` as an `unsigned long long` since he knows the sign-bit is `0`. That's what your assemly output shows.

Now, we can see that there is indeed a bug. Suppose `objArray.size() - 1` does *not* fit into a positive signed `int`. This would cause `i` to overflow, thus cause undefined behaviour which is always bad news.

Comment: size( ) is not signed.  It is doing signed/unsigned comparison which would use the promotion rules https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons

Comment: @Beached doesn't matter. When `i` is negative it already overflowed and you can't say anything about undefined behaviour.

Comment: So what you're saying is that with optimisations turned on it just turned my int declaration into an unsigned long long for simpler comparison?

Comment: @Zebrafish judging from your bytecode, yes. But the important thing is that you can not rely on that behaviour and it may change in the future.

Comment: I don't see how i can be negative, it starts at 0 and is checked if it is less than size( )-1.  size() is not an int but a size_t

Comment: @Beached judging from the assembly, it can not. But the code allows for an overflow, if `sizeof(int) < sizeof(size_t)` (again, strictly speaking overflowing an int is UB)

Comment: Seems there's a major gotcha case in the second answer by Nawaz in that signed/unsigned link. I never would have believed int i = -1; unsigned int j = 1;  i < j is false

Answer (score 0):

Lets dissect the code 
for (int i = 0; i < objArray.size() - 1; ++i)

you are doing a comparison between and int and a size_t.  The size( )-1 is an unsigned underflow when the array is empty and results in a value of std::numeric_limits::max( ).  The comparison, will be signed/unsigned and use the type promotion rules as outlined here [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons)

Comment: Though if it was promoting one type to another it should show up in the assembly, right? I think WorldSender is right when he says that as an optimisation it just turned my int declaration into the size_t type for more efficient comparison.

Comment: It's also UB when size( ) < 1 as the loop index will overflow