# Is there a reason to used an unsigned type for a non-negative constant?

Tags: c++

I saw something like this in a code review:

```
constexpr int64_t SOME_MAX = 2147483647;
```

My initial thought was to add a request to make that an unsigned type, such as a uint64_t. It's my habit to use unsigned ints for values I know should always be positive. But then I wondered whether that added any real value for a constant. Is there any reason to set a non-negative const to an unsigned int type in c++?

Comment: I would reserve ALL UPPERCASE for macros. Using that convention for constants is something that originated with early C, which didn't have named constants so that they had to be expressed as macros.

Comment: *It's my habit to use unsigned ints for values I know should always be positive* How would you ever tell if you were given a negative input?  Personally I use `int` unless I need something bigger and than then I use `long long`.  For me unsigned types are only for bitwise operations

Comment: @NathanOliver If you have a variable for something like degrees Kelvin, then you know you never want the value to be negative. Making it unsigned provides certain compiler checks for this invariant. Checking input for unexpected values is something that has to be done regardless of the type of a variable.

Comment: @firebush: "Making it unsigned provides certain compiler checks for this" **in Pascal**. Not in C++. In C++ the choice of unsigned type expresses the exact opposite, that the compiler shall not complain about range overflows, because unsigned C++ types have guaranteed modulo arithmetic.

Comment: @firebush No it doesn't.  The compiler is perfectly fine doing `5 - 10` to an unsigned type and giving you 5 less than the max value in return.  `unsigned` is not meant to be used to say the value must not be negative.  It is used when you want to have modulo 2^n arithmetic.

Comment: I have helpful answers here, so I guess I can't complain too much if this is now marked "opinion based." There are issues with using unsigned integers, such as comparison with signed integers, that I hadn't taken into account until I saw these answers. Can someone explain why this is an opinion-based question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixing signed and unsigned types can produce compiler warnings and unexpected results.

For example, given `int x = -1`, the expression:

```
if ( x < SOME_MAX )
```

will be `true` if `SOME_MAX` is `int64_t`

will be `false` if `SOME_MAX` is `uint64_t`, as `x` will be implicitly converted to unsigned.

See [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414)

---

You should not make a constant unsigned simply because you know the value is non-negative.

You should choose whether it is unsigned by the contexts it will be used in.

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It's a good observation but it doesn't answer the question. I am surprised that the OP selected it as solution when it doesn't even sniff in the direction of the question, to wit, "is there any reason to set a non-negative const to an unsigned int type in c++?".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I agree.   I suspect(ed) that the *intended* question was more related to the "it's my habit.." line and not the literal interpretation that your post answers _very well_.

Comment: I thought it was clear enough: a constant should be `unsigned` if it will be used in arithmetic with `unsigned` expressions.

Answer (score 5):

> **”** Is there any reason to set a non-negative const to an unsigned int type in c++?

One reason to use an unsigned type for a constant is when it expresses a bitset.

Another reason is when it expresses the max value of the type.

To express that a specific ordinary number must be non-negative you can use an assertion. To just *indicate* that, e.g. for a formal argument, you can use a type name alias, e.g. `using Positive_int = int;`. To enforce it for a given use of numbers you can define a range-checking type.

---

Defining an ordinary number constant as unsigned type risks inadvertent promotion of operator arguments to unsigned, with wrap-around. The undesired effects of that range from nothing, to annoying compiler warnings, to incorrect results. It's a high price to pay for an indication of range, which one can communicate more clearly via a type name alias.

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you for your answer Alf.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason to set a non-negative const to an unsigned int
>   type in c++?

Unsigned should not be used to express the fact that a number should not be negative, because it's a lie; an `unsigned int` cannot be negative, but the language will not complain if you try to set it to a negative number anyway. Even worse, it will silently turn it into a huge positive number instead. That even **prevents error detection**:

```
unsigned int f() { return 1; }
unsigned int g() { return 2; }
unsigned int x = f() - g();
assert(x >= 0); // futile
```

Signed integers allow you to detect the error:

```
int f() { return 1; }
int g() { return 2; }
int x = f() - g();
assert(x >= 0);
```

That being said, you may be dealing with other code that already uses unsigned ints to represent numbers that shouldn't be negative. Unfortunately, this includes the C++ standard library, which uses unsigned sizes for historical reasons. In such situations, it can be an acceptable compromise to use unsigned numbers as well.

As for your code example,

> ```
> constexpr int64_t SOME_MAX = 2147483647;
> ```

I can think of two better ways to express that:

```
auto constexpr some_max = 2147483647;
```

or

```
auto constexpr some_max = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max();
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I'm not sure if the OP means `int32_t` or `int64_t`. Perhaps the `2147483647` value was a bug in the first place.