# Really weird if statement behavior in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, if-statement, vector

Only the first statement is printed even though both if expressions should evaluate the same. Why?

```
    map <int, int> elem;
    vector <int> nums(2);
    int x = 1;
    elem[x]=-1;
    
    int val = elem[x];

    if(val>nums.size()/3) {cout << "First";} // as you can see, vals is -1 and nums.size() is 2
        
    if(-1>2/3) cout<< "Second";
```

Comment: `nums.size()` isn't an `int`

Comment: If you are not asking for help with a compilation error, it's a good idea to make sure your example code compiles [without warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same.

```
if(val > nums.size() / 3) {
```

The problem is that `num.size()` has type of `size_t` which is unsigned. When you compare signed to unsigned type, you get undefined behaviour.

If you really want to make it the same, then you need to do a cast:

```
if (val > static_cast<int>(nums.size()) / 3)
```

now it would be similar to your second code

```
if(-1 > 2 / 3)
```

both of which would result in `false` and you should not see any `First` or `Second` printing.

Comment: Or: `if(-1 > static_cast<size_t>(2) / 3)`

Comment: This is not undefined behavior, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons