# C programming - Decision making

Tags: c, if-statement

```
int main()
{
  if (sizeof(int) > -1)
    printf("Yes");
  else
    printf("No");
}
```

Output should be Yes, but the output is No. what is the logic being used?

Comment: There should be a warning thrown for comparison of signed and unsigned integers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons

Comment: Try `if (sizeof(int) > (__int128_t) -1)` assuming your system supports 128-bit integers with `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: Duplicate: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Answer (score 1):

For your question, you need to understand how the type conversion is done.
C specifies:

> - If either operand is of type long double, the other shall be converted to long double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be converted to float.
> - **Otherwise, if either operand is unsigned, the other shall be converted to unsigned.**

So what happens is that the `sizeof(int)` operator returns an unsigned value which is being compared to signed value. Hence, -1 will be converted to an unsigned integer which in turn returns the answer `No`.

So as @user3386109 has pointed out, you can add (__int128_t) before -1.
You can also write (__int128) with `t` omitted.

So your final code will be:

```
int main()
{
  if (sizeof(int) >  (__int128) -1)
    printf("Yes");
  else
    printf("No");
}
```

which gives the answer `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof()` returns a value of type `size_t`, which is an alias of an implementation-defined **unsigned** integral type.

Therefore, the other term is converted into unsigned type also!

So `-1` becomes SIZE_MAX, and hence the test becomes `if (sizeof(int) > SIZE_MAX)` hence, the output you get - not what you expect.

This is explained further in
[Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons)

Comment: You probably mean `SIZE_MAX`? Although `SIZE_MAX` for a 64 bit `size_t` is not necessarily `2^64`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks.