# Why does this loop run?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
std::string qaz{};
vector <size_t> index ;
cout <<"qaz: "<<qaz<<" length: "<<qaz.length()<<"\n";  
for (size_t i{0}; i<= ( qaz.length()-2);i++ )
{   cout<<"Entered"<<i<<"\n";      
    cout<<"Exited"<<i<<"\n";}

return 0;
}
```

//Here **qaz** is an empty string so **qaz.length() == 0** (so **qaz.length()-2 == -2**) and **i** is initialized to **0** so I expected that we will not enter the loop. But on running it I find that it goes on in an infinite loop. Why? Please help me with it.

Comment: `( qaz.length()-2)` is a large number due to unsigned arithmetic. Oops. Write `i + 2 <=  qaz.length()` instead. The actual loop is finite, by the way.

Comment: `length` returns a `size_t` which is an *unsigned* integral type. Subtracting 2 from that leads to underflow, returning a very big number insted

Comment: When you're absolutely sure that `qaz.length()-2 == -2`, but a loop executes anyway, it is the perfect time to add `cout << qaz.length()-2 << '\n';`

Answer (score 3):

See [docs for `size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t):

> `std::size_t` is the **unsigned** integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator

(Emphasis mine.)

Furthermore, [`string::length` returns a `size_t` too](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/)<sup>1</sup>.

But even if that were not the case, when comparing signed values to unsigned values, the signed value is converted to unsigned before the comparison, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5416498/1871033).

`(size_t)0 - 2` will [underflow](https://vladris.com/blog/2018/10/13/arithmetic-overflow-and-underflow.html) as `size_t` is unsigned and therefore its minimum value is zero resulting in a large number which is usually<sup>2</sup> either 2<sup>32</sup>-2 or 2<sup>64</sup>-2 depending on the processor architecture. Let's go with the latter, then you will get 18,446,744,073,709,552,000 as result.

Now, looking at the result of `0 <= 18446744073709552000` you can see that zero is clearly less than or equal to 18.4 quintillion, so the loop condition is fulfilled. In fact the loop is not infinite, it will loop exactly 18,446,744,073,709,552,001 times, but it's true you will probably not want to wait for it to finally reach its finishing point.

The solution is to avoid the underflow by comparing `i + y <= x` instead of `i <= x - y`<sup>3</sup>, i.e. `i + 2 <= qaz.length()`. You will then have `2 <= 0` which is false.

---

<sub>**1:** Technically, it returns an `std::allocator<char>::size_type` but that is defined as `std::size_t`.</sub>

<sub>**2:** To be exact, it is `SIZE_MAX - (2 - 1)` i.e. `SIZE_MAX - 1` (see [limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)). In terms of numeric value, it could also be 2<sup>16</sup>-2 - such as on an ATmega328P microcontroller - or some other value, but on the architectures you get on desktop computers at the current point in time it's most likely one of the two I mentioned. It depends on the width of the `std::size_t` type. If it's X bits wide, you'd get 2<sup>X</sup>-n for `(size_t)0 - n` for 0<n<2<sup>X</sup>. Since C++11 it is however guaranteed that `std::size_t` is no less than 16 bits wide.</sub>

<sub>**3:** However, in the unlikely case that your length is very large, specifically at least the number calculated above with 2<sup>X</sup>-2 or larger, this would result in an *overflow* instead. But in that case your whole logic would be flawed and you'd need a different approach. I *think* this can't be the case anyway because `std::ssize` support means that string lengths would have to have one unused bit to be repurposed as sign bit, but I think this answer went down various rabbit holes far enough already.</sub>

Comment: (Note that from C++11, the bit width of `std::size_t` is not less than 16).

Comment: Yes indeed, I think you are right.

Comment: On (3) I'm pretty sure a string length must be expressible with one excess bit of the unsigned type remaining, in order to support ssize. In other words, adding 2 cannot cause overflow.

Comment: Added some additional comment in that regard but that's it, I give up ;) Feel free to edit my answer further if you deem it worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

`length()` returns unsigned value, which cannot be below zero. `0u - 2` wraps around and becomes very large number.

Use `i + 2 <= qaz.length()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `size_t` is unsigned. `length()` returns the strings `size_type` which is unsigned and most likely also `size_t`. When the strings size is `<2` then `length() -2` wraps around to yield a large unsigned value.

Since C++20 there is `std::ssize` which returns a signed value. Though you also have to adjust the type of `i` to get correct number of iterations also when `i < -2` is the condition:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::string qaz{};
    vector <size_t> index ;
    cout <<"qaz: "<<qaz<<" length: "<<qaz.length()<<"\n";  
    for (int i{0}; i<= ( std::ssize(qaz)-2);i++ )
    {   
        cout<<"Entered"<<i<<"\n";      
        cout<<"Exited"<<i<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Alternatively stay with unsigneds and use `i+2 <= qaz.length()`.