# Why this c++ for loop is going into infinite loop

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

The value for i keeps decreasing forever. Technically it should stop after first iteration because ans.size()-k = 0, but it doesn't stop. If I put 0 manually over there then it works completely fine.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     vector<int> ans(1);
     int k = 1;
     for (int i = ans.size() - 1; i >= ans.size() - k; --i)
     {
          cout << i << endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: Relevant: [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5416414/580083)

Comment: Please [enable warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) on your compiler. It will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: -> `i + k >= ans.size()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes so it should stop when i goes to -1 becasue -1 + 1 = 0 which is not greater than 1 (size of ans vector)

Comment: @UtsavPatel `ans.size()` is **unsigned**, there is no `-1` unsigned value. That it why your version does not work (and Jarod42's version does work). C++ math is not the same as normal math, and the problems when you mix signed and unsigned values are one example of that.