# For loop in c++ is not running while using this way: for(int i=-1;i<vector.size();i++) cout << i << endl;

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a particular use case where I have to initialize i value in for loop to -1 and write the exiting condition based on vector size. But the problem is the loop is not getting executed at all.
This is the code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for(int i=-1;i<vec.size();i++) cout << i << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

But I am able to do like this.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int size = vec.size();
    for(int i=-1;i<size;i++) cout << i << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain this weird behavior or am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: You are comparing an `int` and a `vector<int>::size_type` (aka `size_t`), which is unsigned.   Change the type of `i` to `size_t`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons

Comment: @MarshalClow OP says *I have to initialize i value in for loop to -1* ... that would be tricky if `i` is a `size_t`.

Comment: There are numerous posts on Stack Overflow explaining that the return type of a vector's `size()` function is an **unsigned** integer value and how to deal with that. I can't find a *specific* example of wanting to start a loop from -1, but search this site for "[c++] vector size unsigned" and you'll likely get some ideas.

Comment: ... but, you can either use your second code snippet or cast the `vec.size()` result to an `int` ... assuming the size of the vector will never be larger than `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i<size()` in the first snippet compares a signed `int i;` to an unsigned `size_t size;` (`size_t` is the typical typedef for `vector::size_type`)

When the compiler sees that comparison, it converts the `int` to an unsigned value. Typically something like `2^64 - 1`, for your first value of `-1`. This value is much bigger than 5, so the loop doesn't run.

Take-away: Don't compare signed and unsigned value with less-than or greater-than.

In fact, in a modern world you can compare signed and unsigned using `std::cmp_less` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp

Comment: Why does the compiler convert the int to an unsigned? Why can't it convert the unsigned to an int?

Comment: This is what the standard specifies. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons

Comment: So what about a system (though it would be unusual) where `int` is 64 bits and `size_t` is 32 bits? OP's *first* code snippet would probably work, then.

Comment: ... BTW, I'm not deliberately trying to be awkward, Just trying to offer hints as to how your answer can be improved. Sorry if I have come across as being a bit truculent.