# How to enable warnings through pragma?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, pragma

I'm trying to enable some warnings that detail potential security problems through a pragma. The warnings are those listed by Jon Sturgeon in [“Off By Default” Compiler Warnings in Visual C++](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/12/14/off-by-default-compiler-warnings-in-visual-c.aspx):

```
# pragma warning (enable: 4191 4242 4263 4264 4265 4266 4302 4826 4905 4906 4928)
```

I'm getting a warning under Visual Studio (2010 to be exact) for the above pragma:

```
ClCompile:
  pch.cpp
  ... config.h(238): warning C4615: #pragma warning : unknown user warning type
```

It appears there is no `enable` or `on` for `pragma warning`. There is a `once`, but I want to see all instances of the potential problems, and not just one.

[Microsoft's documentation on warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) does not appear to discuss the topic of enabling warnings.

I can't really use `# pragma warning (default: ...)` because they are off by default. I don't want to modify each of the solution's configurations because the solution has  4 projects, 6 configurations and 4 platforms. So I have 80+ of them to change (the cross product of the selections).

How do I enable select warnings through the pragma?

Comment: possible a duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151908/enable-a-single-warning-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks Marged. Its close, but I don't think so because the two answers offer: (1) do it in the solution's configuration, and (2) use `pragma warning (default: ...)`. I specifically want to avoid it in the configuration because the solution has 4 projects, 6 configurations and 4 platforms. That means I have to potentially touch it in 80 places.

Comment: It should be `error` not `enable` as `in #pragma warning (error: 4191 4242 4263 4264 4265 4266 4302 4826 4905 4906 4928)`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - But won't `error` stop the compile? I want the compile to complete. My requirement (for release engineering) is a clean compile. I don't care what happens up until that point. The developers would tar and feather me if I stopped their compilation process for no reason.

Comment: You are right. That's no good. How about #pragma warning( push, 4 ) ... followed by #pragma pop? I guess you have already seen that though

Comment: From the MSDN link, if you `#pragma warning(X: a b c d)`, where X is 1,2,3,4 and 'a b c d' are your warnings, it says `This also turns on a specified warning that is off by default.` .. so would `# pragma warning (1: 4191 4242 4263 4264 4265 4266 4302 4826 4905 4906 4928)` and enable a warning level of 1 not suffice? Then do a `# pragma warning (default: 4191 4242 4263 4264 4265 4266 4302 4826 4905 4906 4928)` which would put them back in the default level/state .. I could be reading that wrong as I don't usually mess with the MS specific `pragmas` ..?

Comment: Check out here: [Enable a single warning in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151908/enable-a-single-warning-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Hmmm... This is on the first page for using a search engine with `site:stackoverflow.com GCC pragma warnings as errors`... It is probably the right-hand panel that introduces the noise.