# Enable/disable warnings, visual studio comand prompt

Tags: visual-studio, command, warnings, disable

I know that this question is almost the same with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151908/enable-a-single-warning-in-visual-studio) , but I still don't understand how to do it in command prompt. Here is what I'm doing:

1. I need to compile old [source code](https://github.com/kornelski/7z/releases/tag/4.62) of 7z archivation tool, so I downloaded it.
2. Now I am running nmake in the 7z_version/CPP/7zip and it shows me errors:

> C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated.

So here is the question: how to disable this warning? I am using VS comand prompt, because IDE cannot understand the project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not a warning, but an error (about the warning being treated as an error). So either you fix the original warning (should be printed a bit earlier in the build log) or you modify the compiler options to not treat warnings as errors: remove the `/WX` flag, or if the project file is msbuild based then set `TreatWarningAsError` to false.

*edit* this is nmake based, remove `-WX` from line 26 in CPP\Build.mak

Comment: But how or where to set this flag(/WX)? I tried set cl = /W0 but that doesn't work